# Nav bar is not showing on webpage

Tags: html, css, navigation

I'm not sure where my navigation is. when i open using google chrome or IE the webpage has no navigation bar. Why is this and what do i need to fix?

html

```
<header class= 'main-header' >
               <div class="logo">
                    !# insert logo picture
               </div>
    <div id="nav">
               <ul id="nav">
                        <li><a href="/home/">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about/">About Us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/news/">News & Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/classes/">Classes & Camps</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/gallery/">Gallery</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/contact/">Contact us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/enrol/">Enrol Now</a></li>
                </ul>
          </div>
        </header>
```

css

```
#content {
   width: 50em;
   margin: 0 auto;
   padding: 40px 0;

}

ul#nav {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

ul#nav li  {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 8px 5px 3px 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    text-decoration: none; 
    padding: .2em 1em;
}
```

any ideas?
Note: im trying to place the navigator at the top of my webpage.
Also I have placed it on a header, could it simply be beneath it?

css for header

```
.main-header {
overflow: hidden;
left: 0;
height:150px;
width: 100%;
background-color: black;
padding: 0px;
margin-left: 0px;
position: absolute;
top: -50px;

}
```

Comment: Try remove the `top` value and see what happens. http://jsfiddle.net/QMqvp/3/

Comment: i can able to see the navigation. check http://jsfiddle.net/Jh9m2/. what is the problem?

Comment: you put top:-50px to .main-header, so that it goes top. Also try to learn positions and its usages.

Comment: ilmk when i remove top:-50px i am able to see my nav bar again although my header does not stay on the top of my webpage it moves down slightly. Can you give me any recommendations onto how to have my header fixed to the top of my webpage without writing top: -50px?

Comment: Not sure if it is what is causing the issue but you are using the id "nav" twice, you must only use an ID once per page as it must be unique!

Comment: you mean like this http://jsfiddle.net/n3RAH/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the top:-50px

and add this

```
html, body{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```

and your header should start on the top-left corner of the side